# Bidirectional USB and battery to charger in a microcontroller circuit

Tags: power-supply, batteries, usb, charger

This is the circuit that I have designed to have connection to both USB and battery as well as an external 12V charger (VCC line).

My requirements are:

- The USB should be OTG. It should be able to both give and receive current.
- The battery is to be Li-Po. I should both give power to the circuit and being charged.

The output are +5V and +3.3V lines to feed different circuit parts.

Is this circuit working? And do I need to fix/improve it?

My concerns are:

- I also suspect AM1117 ICs as they can only reduce voltage and they are not buck-boost.
- I also suspect the power direction for USB and battery can be bi-directional.

[image: USB and Battery to charge micro-controller]

List of used ICs:

- AO8820: N-channel MOSFET transistor for switching applications
- FPF2109: Power Switch/Driver 1:1 P-Channel 200mA
- FPF2004: Power Switch/Driver 1:1 P-Channel 100mA
- AMS1117: Linear Voltage Regulator IC Positive Fixed 1 Output 1A
- S-8261: Battery protection IC with overcharge and overdischarge protection
- USBLC6-2SC6: ESD protection for USB interfaces(17V Clamp 5A (8/20µs) Ipp Tvs Diode)

Comment: Is this circuit working? You designed it, so you should tell us if it works or not..